# Uso de los headers de la liberia csvimport

Tags: php, csv

estoy usando la libreria csvimport de php para realizar una carga masiva de datos, ya funciona correctamente pero necesito subir el archivo sin headers y darle unos predeterminados en php, ¿Alguien que conozca o entienda la libreria me podria guiar?

Tambien me suele ocurrir que la primera columna del csv no la reconoce al recorrer el archivo subido en un arreglo, ¿Que puede ser?

Libreria: https://github.com/bradstinson/csv-import/blob/master/libraries/csvimport.php

Gracias.

```
//Metodo
      public function importar_csv(){



        $this->csvimport->delimiter(';');

        $datos_csv = $this->csvimport->get_array($_FILES["archivo_csv"]["tmp_name"]);

        foreach ($datos_csv as $row) {




         $regiones = $this->Asignaciones_model->get_id_region($row["region"]);
         $dias_mora = $this->Asignaciones_model->get_id_mora($row["edad mora"]);
         $responsables_cobro = $this->Asignaciones_model->get_id_cod_agencia($row["responsable cobro"]);
         $tipos_inventario = $this->Asignaciones_model->get_id_tipo_inventario($row["tipo inventario"]);


         $fecha_inicio_m = str_replace('/', '-', $row["fecha inicio mora"]);
         $nueva_fecha_inicio_m = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fecha_inicio_m));



         $fecha_translados = str_replace('/', '-', $row["fecha translados"]);
         $nueva_fecha_translados = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fecha_translados));

         $datos[] = array(

           'referencia_pago' => $row["referencia pago"],
           'nombres' => $row["nombres"],
           'identificacion' => $row["identificacion"],
           'saldo' => $row["saldo"],
           'corriente' => $row["corriente"],
           'intereses_mora' => $row["intereses mora"],
           'honorarios' => $row["honorarios"],
           'region_id' => $regiones->id,
           'ciclo_id' => $row["ciclo"],
           'fecha_inicio_mora' => $nueva_fecha_inicio_m,
           'dias_mora' => $row["dias mora"],
           'mora_id' => $dias_mora->id,
           'fecha_translados' => $nueva_fecha_translados,
           'cod_agencia_id' => $responsables_cobro->id,
           'valor_a_cobrar' => $row["valor a cobrar"],
           'dias_mora' => $row["dias mora"],
           'descripcion_translado' => $row["descripcion translado"],
           'tipo_inventario_id' => $tipos_inventario->id,
           'num_asignacion_translado' => $row["numero asignacion translado"],
           'marca_portafolio' => $row["marca portafolio"],
           'agencia' => $responsables_cobro->cod_agencia.$regiones->cod_regional


         );    



       }



       $this->Asignaciones_model->insertar($datos);





     }
```

Comment: Por favor agrega tu código a tu pregunta...

Comment: Listo, código agregado